ORA-12541: No TNS Listener
I have a problem connecting to my Oracle database from my VB.NET application. I am using the System.Data.OracleClient namespace. When calling connection.Open() with specifying the correct connection string (see below), I get the error ORA-12541: No TNS listener. I have tried following things:

Installing the Oracle client on my development machine
Checked the listener with lsnrctl on my database machine - listener is running and ready
Tried tnsping from the development machine to the database machine - it succeeded
Connection to the database via sqlplus command does work as well.

I have tried the following connections, both failing with the same issue:

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.127)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SID = xe)));Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd;
Data Source=XE;User ID=user;Password=pwd

where XE is defined in tsnames.ora as follows:
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.10.127)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = xe)
    )
  )

As mentioned above, both tnsping 192.168.10.127 and tnsping XE succeed.
I am using a Oracle 21c Database, with .NET-Framework v4.8.

First think drawing attention: the usage of "SID" with ORACLE 21... try with "service_name" instead.

Does lsnrctl definitely report the same address and port you are using to connect? If so are the two machines on the same network, or is there a VPN involved, or a proxy?

You said that sqlplus works, so whatever TNS string you are using for sqlplus should work as well for another client on the same host, assuming any alias is being resolved to the same tnsnames.ora or ldap.ora configuration. Check the env variable $TNS_ADMIN to ensure it either isn't set or is set to the same value in both clients.  Verify the IP (or resolved IP of the host) and the port match what lsnrctl reports the listener to be listening on. Double check the vb.net docs on whether the Data Source=... syntax is correct, whether it allows spaces, equal signs and parentheses.

Appreciate your help, but it did turn out there was some sort of hidden config file, which had the wrong hostname in it. I did not develop the application myself, so I don't know why there are 2 locations where you have to enter the right hostname. However, I got it up running now, thank you all!
